# Google calendar, get days with activities

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to get a list of dates (separated by day) with activities, sending time boundaries in the request.

For example:

request:

```
{
  minDate: 'someMinDate',
  maxDate: 'someMaxDate'
}
```

response:

```
{
  datesWithActivities: [
    'day1',
    'day2',
    'day3'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentations, you should be able to use the `list` method:

```
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list
```

and use its `timeMin` and `timeMax` parameters.

Here are example requests with `timeMin` and `timeMax` set to '2016-05-18T07:00:00+07:00' and '2016-05-18T09:00:00+07:00' respectively:

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/ariefbayu%40gmail.com/events?timeMax=2016-05-18T09%3A00%3A00%2B07%3A00&timeMin=2016-05-18T07%3A00%3A00%2B07%3A00&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Activities in Google Calendar are called **Events**, and by requesting the events of the calendar using the [`list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#http-request) method, and passing the `timeMax` and `timeMin` parameters in the request you get events between the dates and times of your choosing.

To get the exact representation you want directly from the API response is not possible with existing methods, you would have to do that on your end.

But feel free to file a Feature Request at https://issuetracker.google.com

---

#### Further reading:

- [Calendar API: Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)